# Can we prevent deleting clodwatch log groups?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

In my production account I have multiple cloudwatch log groups which should not be deleted under any circumstances. I could not find any strait forward way to do this. Appreciate your support if there a way I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

You have three options.

First, you can define granular access to those log groups, and simply not grant the `DeleteLogGroup` permission. This is, IMO, the best approach.

Second, you can create a [permissions boundary](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_boundaries.html), which is attached to all of the IAM users/roles that can access the log groups in question, and denies the `DeleteLogGroup` permission. The drawback to permissions policies is that you have to apply them everywhere.

Third, if you have set up an organization, you can create a [service control policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html) that explicitly denies `DeleteLogGroup` for those log groups. Apply this to the account(s), and nobody, not even the root user, will be able to delete the group(s).

If you go with the third option, be sure to read through the documentation on AWS Organizations. One thing that AWS recommends is that the organization root account not be used for any workloads, so you should create a new account to serve as the organization root and invite your current account.

Answer (score 0):

By setting up a retention policy that ensures logs are never deleted, they can be protected via a retention policy.Further more details checkout this link [Retention Policy Cloud Watch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_PutRetentionPolicy.html)

Comment: Actually I already have the retention policy, what I need to prevent by deleting the log groups manually or any other means

Comment: Manually you can set the permissions of the users and roles that have access to that logs groups make sure only authorise  personnel can access the group.